# Generate a planet from the rpg Traveller system in python

Tags: python, object-oriented

I've been trying to teach myself to use object oriented code, and I thought a fun way to learn would be to write a class of planets, based on the rule system of Mongoose Traveller.

When a planet object is created, it algorithmically generates a planet. 
I defined a string method and a json method for returning the planet data. 
The function two_dice() simulates the sum of two dice rolls.

```
from models.common import two_dice
from random import randint

# Translate int values to string equivalent
numMap = {0: '0', 1: '1', 2: '2', 3: '3', 4: '4', 5: '5', 6: '6', 7: '7', 8: '8', 9: '9', 10: 'A', 11: 'B', 12: 'C',
          13: 'D', 14: 'E', 15: 'F', '-': '-'}


class Planet(object):
    def __init__(self, name, **kwargs):
        """
        creates a planet object with algorithmically defined attributes
        Attributes can be passed as keywords and creation process will account for them
        """
        self.name = name
        # Size is 2D - 2
        self.size = self._check_kwargs("size", 10, 0, kwargs)
        if self.size is None:
            self.size = two_dice()-2
        # Atmosphere is Size + 2D - 7. If size = 0, atmosphere = 0
        self.atmosphere = self._check_kwargs('atmosphere', 15, 0, kwargs)
        if self.atmosphere is None:
            self.atmosphere = self.size+two_dice()-7
            if self.size == 0:
                self.atmosphere = 0
            self.atmosphere = max(0, self.atmosphere)
        # Temperature is 2D. Affected by atmosphere type
        self.temperature = self._check_kwargs('temperature', 12, 0, kwargs)
        if self.temperature is None:
            self.temperature = two_dice()
            if self.atmosphere in [2, 3]:
                self.temperature -= 2
            elif self.atmosphere in [4, 5, 14]:
                self.temperature -= 2
            elif self.atmosphere in [8, 9]:
                self.temperature += 1
            elif self.atmosphere in [10, 13, 15]:
                self.temperature += 2
            elif self.atmosphere in [11, 12]:
                self.temperature += 6
            self.temperature = max(0, self.temperature)
            self.temperature = min(12, self.temperature)
        # Hydrographics is atmosphere + 2D - 7. Affected by size, temperature and atmosphere
        self.hydrographics = self._check_kwargs('hydrographics', 10, 0, kwargs)
        if self.hydrographics is None:
            if self.size <= 1:
                self.hydrographics = 0
            else:
                self.hydrographics = self.atmosphere + two_dice() - 7
                if self.atmosphere in [0, 1, 10, 11, 12]:
                    self.hydrographics -= 4
                if self.atmosphere != 13:
                    if self.temperature in [10, 11]:
                        self.hydrographics -= 2
                    elif self.temperature >= 12:
                        self.hydrographics -= 6
            self.hydrographics = max(0, self.hydrographics)
            self.hydrographics = min(10, self.hydrographics)
        # Population is 2D - 2.
        self.population = self._check_kwargs('population', 12, 0, kwargs)
        if self.population is None:
            self.population = two_dice() - 2
        # Government is population + 2D - 7.
        self.government = self._check_kwargs('government', 15, 0, kwargs)
        if self.government is None:
            self.government = self.population + two_dice() - 7
            if self.population == 0:
                self.government = 0
            self.government = max(0, self.government)
            self.government = min(15, self.government)
        # Culture is determined by rolling two dice, and concatenating the result.
        self.culture = randint(1, 6) + randint(1, 6) * 10
        if self.population == 0:
            self.culture = 0
        # Law level is government + 2D - 7
        self.law_level = self._check_kwargs('law_level', 9, 0, kwargs)
        if self.law_level is None:
            self.law_level = self.government + two_dice() - 7
            if self.population == 0:
                self.law_level = 0
            self.law_level = max(0, self.law_level)
            self.law_level = min(9, self.law_level)
        # Starport level is 2D, affected by population
        self.starport = self._check_kwargs('starport', 12, 0, kwargs)
        if self.starport is None:
            self.starport = two_dice()
            if self.population >= 10:
                self.starport += 2
            elif self.population >= 8:
                self.starport += 1
            elif self.population <= 2:
                self.starport -= 2
            elif self.population <= 4:
                self.starport -= 1
            self.starport = min(12, self.starport)
            self.starport = max(0, self.starport)
        # tech level is 1D, affected by lots of modifiers
        self.tech_level = self._check_kwargs('tech_level', 15, 0, kwargs)
        if self.tech_level is None:
            self.tech_level = randint(1, 6)
            if self.atmosphere <= 3 or self.atmosphere >= 10:
                self.tech_level += 1
            if self.size in [0, 1]:
                self.tech_level += 2
            elif self.size in [2, 3, 4]:
                self.tech_level += 1
            if self.hydrographics in [0, 9]:
                self.tech_level += 1
            elif self.hydrographics == 10:
                self.tech_level += 2
            if self.population in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8]:
                self.tech_level += 1
            elif self.population == 9:
                self.tech_level += 2
            elif self.population == 10:
                self.tech_level += 4
            if self.government in [0, 5]:
                self.tech_level += 1
            elif self.government in [13, 14]:
                self.tech_level -= 2
            elif self.government == 7:
                self.tech_level += 2
            if self.starport >= 11:
                self.tech_level += 6
            elif self.starport >= 9:
                self.tech_level += 4
            elif self.starport >= 7:
                self.tech_level += 2
            elif self.starport <= 2:
                self.tech_level -= 4
            if self.population == 0:
                self.tech_level = 0
            self.tech_level = max(0, self.tech_level)
            self.tech_level = min(15, self.tech_level)

    @staticmethod
    def _check_kwargs(keyword, maxvalue, minvalue, kwargs):
        """
        Checks the given keyword exists, and is between given max & min values
        Returns keyword value if exists, otherwise None
        """
        if keyword in kwargs:
            if maxvalue >= kwargs[keyword] >= minvalue:
                return kwargs[keyword]
            else:
                raise ValueError("{} must be between {} and {}".format(keyword, maxvalue, minvalue))
        else:
            return None

    def json(self):
        return {'name': self.name,
                'size': self.size,
                'atmosphere': self.atmosphere,
                'temperature': self.temperature,
                'hydrographics': self.hydrographics,
                'population': self.population,
                'government': self.government,
                'culture': self.culture,
                'law_level': self.law_level,
                'starport': self.starport,
                'tech_level': self.tech_level}

    def __str__(self):
        attributes_list = [self.size, self.atmosphere, self.hydrographics, self.population, self.government,
                           self.law_level, '-', self.tech_level]
        if self.starport <= 2:
            starport = 'X'
        elif self.starport <= 4:
            starport = 'E'
        elif self.starport <= 6:
            starport = 'D'
        elif self.starport <= 8:
            starport = 'C'
        elif self.starport <= 10:
            starport = 'B'
        else:
            starport = 'A'
        return self.name + ' ' + starport + ''.join(list(map(lambda X: numMap[X],attributes_list)))
```

This is my first attempt at writing a class. Although it is currently stand alone, I would like for it to be able to fit inside a larger project. Are there any ways I can improve this so that it better follows best practices, and removes repetitive code?

Comment: I'm assuming you're building a space RPG planet generator of sorts?

Comment: Yes, it's a recreation of the planet generation rules in the pen and paper rpg Traveller. You can find the rules here if you're interested http://www.traveller-srd.com/core-rules/world-creation/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. There does not seem to be a way to pass `culture` as a keyword argument. This looks like an oversight.
2. There is no check for invalid keyword arguments. This means that if we make a typographical error, we won't find out about it, but the result will be wrong:

   ```
   >>> planet = Planet('Hrod', atmopshere=10)
   >>> planet.atmosphere
   7
   ```

   It would be better to raise an exception like this:

   ```
   TypeError: 'atmopshere' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
   ```
3. The function `two_dice` seems oddly specific. Traveller uses a lot of 2d6 rolls, but in the code I can see expressions like `randint(1, 6)` and `two_dice() - 7`. I think something like this would be helpful:

   ```
   import re

   def roll(dice):
       """Roll dice and return their sum. The argument must be a string
       describing the roll, for example '2d6+3' to roll two 6-sided dice
       and add three.

       """
       match = re.match(r'([1-9]\d*)d([1-9]\d*)([+-]\d+)?$', dice)
       if not match:
           raise ValueError(f"Expected dice but got {dice!r}")
       n, sides, bonus = match.groups()
       sides = int(sides)
       return sum(randint(1, sides) for _ in range(int(n))) + int(bonus or 0)
   ```

   Then you can write `roll('1d6')` or `roll('2d6-7')` which might be clearer to the reader and easier to check against the rulebook.
4. The temperature is adjusted by the same value (−2) for two different sets of values for the atmosphere:

   ```
   if self.atmosphere in [2, 3]:
       self.temperature -= 2
   elif self.atmosphere in [4, 5, 14]:
       self.temperature -= 2
   ```

   Is that last line a typo for `self.temperature -= 1`?
5. `numMap` maps integers from 0 to 15 to their hexadecimal equivalant, and also hyphen to itself. If it weren't for the hyphen you could write `format(n, 'X')` and not need the `numMap`. Looking at the use of `numMap` it seems that the point of the hyphen is to implement a special case in the `__str__` method. But as it says in the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/),

   > Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.

   So I would recommend making `__str__` a bit more complicated in order to elimate the special case, which would allow you to use `format(..., 'X')`, which in turn would allow you to get rid of `numMap`.
6. There's a lot of repetition. For each attribute, we have a *name*, we have a *maximum* value, and we might need to include its hexadecimal digit in the string code. We can put this data into a table, like this:

   ```
   _ATTRIBUTES = [
       # Name,      maximum, code
       ('size',          10, True),
       ('atmosphere',    15, True),
       ('temperature',   12, False),
       ('hydrographics', 10, True),
       ('population',    12, True),
       ('government',    15, True),
       ('law_level',      9, True),
       ('starport',      12, False),
       ('tech_level',    15, False),
       ('culture',       66, False),
   ]
   ```

   And we could put the rules for generating each attribute into their own methods, like this:

   ```
   def _size_default(self):
       return roll('2d6-2')

   def _atmosphere_default(self):
       if self.size == 0:
           return 0
       else:
           return self.size + roll('2d6-7')

   _TEMPERATURE_ADJUST = [0, 0, -2, -2, -1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 6, 6, 1, -1, 1]

   def _temperature_default(self):
       return roll('2d6') + self._TEMPERATURE_ADJUST[self.atmosphere]

   def _hydrographics_default(self):
       if self.size <= 1:
           return 0
       hydrographics = self.atmosphere + roll('2d6-7')
       if self.atmosphere in (0, 1, 10, 11, 12):
           hydrographics -= 4
       if self.atmosphere != 13:
           if self.temperature in (10, 11):
               hydrographics -= 2
           elif self.temperature >= 12:
               hydrographics -= 6
       return hydrographics

   def _population_default(self):
       return roll('2d6-2')

   def _government_default(self):
       if self.population == 0:
           return 0
       else:
           return self.population + roll('2d6-7')

   def _culture_default(self):
       if self.population == 0:
           return 0
       else:
           return roll('1d6') * 10 + roll('1d6')

   def _law_level_default(self):
       if self.population == 0:
           return 0
       else:
           return self.government + roll('2d6-7')

   _STARPORT_ADJUST = [-2, -2, -2, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]

   def _starport_default(self):
       return roll('2d6') + self._STARPORT_ADJUST[self.population]

   _TECH_LEVEL_ADJUST = [
       # attribute, {value:adjustment}
       ('size', {0:2, 1:2, 2:1, 3:1, 4:1}),
       ('atmosphere', {0:1, 1:1, 2:1, 3:1, 10:1, 11:1, 12:1, 13:1,
                       14:1, 15:1}),
       ('hydrographics', {0:1, 9:1, 10:2}),
       ('population', {1:1, 2:1, 3:1, 4:1, 5:1, 8:1, 9:2, 10:4}),
       ('government', {0:1, 5:1, 7:2, 13:-2, 14:-2}),
       ('starport', {0:-4, 1:-4, 2:-4, 7:2, 8:2, 9:4, 10:4, 11:6, 12:6,
                     13:6, 14:6, 15:6}),
   ]

   def _tech_level_default(self):
       if self.population == 0:
           return 0
       tech_level = roll('1d6')
       for attribute, adjustment in self._TECH_LEVEL_ADJUST:
           tech_level += adjustment.get(getattr(self, attribute), 0)
       return tech_level
   ```

   Now we can process the keyword arguments systematically, like this, fixing points §1 and §2 above, and avoiding the repetition:

   ```
   for attribute, maximum, _ in self._ATTRIBUTES:
       if attribute in kwargs:
           value = kwargs.pop(attribute)
           if not (0 <= value <= maximum):
               raise ValueError(f"{attribute!r} must be between 0 and "
                                "{maximum} inclusive")
       else:
           value = getattr(self, '_' + attribute + '_default')()
           value = max(0, min(value, maximum))
       setattr(self, attribute, value)
   if kwargs:
       kwarg = next(iter(kwargs))
       raise TypeError(f"{kwarg!r} is an invalid keyword argument for "
                       "this function")
   ```

   After doing this, we don't need `_check_kwargs` any more, and the `json` and `__str__` methods become:

   ```
   def json(self):
       result = dict(name=self.name)
       for attribute, _, _ in self._ATTRIBUTES:
           result[attribute] = getattr(self, attribute)
       return result

   _STARPORT_CODE = 'XXXEEDDCCBBAAAAA'

   def __str__(self):
       return "{} {}{}-{}".format(
           self.name,
           self._STARPORT_CODE[self.starport],
           ''.join(format(getattr(self, attribute), 'X')
                   for attribute, _, code in self._ATTRIBUTES if code),
           format(self.tech_level, 'X'))
   ```

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you use `[1-9]\d*` in the regex in `roll(dice)`, and not `\d+`?

Comment: Also (maybe related), are these typos in `_size_default` (`roll(2d-2)`) and `_atmosphere_default` (`roll(2d-7)`)? They don't seem to match the dice roll syntax.

Comment: @mkrieger1: (i) Errors now fixed, thank you. (ii) Requiring a non-zero digit catches mistakes like `0d6` or `2d0`, and generates a better error message than `ValueError: empty range for randrange() (1,1, 0)`.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that it was `[1-9]`, not `[0-9]`. That explains a lot.